# Next.JS: Resolver with promise doesn't work in api-routes-server-and-client-test on SSR

Tags: node.js, async-await, graphql, apollo, next.js

Using next.js example [api-routes-apollo-server-and-client](https://github.com/zeit/next.js/tree/canary/examples/api-routes-apollo-server-and-client). When I'm trying to implement delay in `apollo/resolvers.js` this way:

```
export const resolvers = {
  Query: {
    viewer (_parent, _args, _context, _info) {
      return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        setTimeout(() => {
          resolve({ id: 1, name: 'John Smith', status: 'cached' });
        }, 1000);
      })
    }
  }
}
```

[image]

This doesn't work in SSR. The data is empty in the SSR apollo state but user data expected `{ id: 1, name: 'John Smith', status: 'cached' }`.

I'm using that also with sequelize to fetch the data from database and it doesn't work too. I guess the reason is the same.

Maybe I'm doing something wrong.

Client-side part works fine (data are displayed after React hydratation).

If we're doing static object instead of Promise:

```
export const resolvers = {
  Query: {
    viewer (_parent, _args, _context, _info) {
      return { id: 1, name: 'John Smith', status: 'cached' };
    }
  }
}
```

Everything works fine and this puts object to initial state returned from SSR server with correct static markup...

[image]

**What am I expecting?**

I want just server render graphql requiest, finish promises, the put the data to apollo state for SSR and does the SSR for SEO purposes. Because for now if I connect to the database - it doesn't work at all (nothing's rendered. just empty page because rendering was interrupted by something).

Comment: Please show the calling code.  ALL `async` functions return a promise so the caller has to use `await` or `.then()` to get the value from the returned promise.  Also, `return await new Promise()` does nothing useful over `return new Promise()`.  And, in fact, your function doesn't even need to be `async` as it finds no benefit from that either.

Comment: @jfriend00 I know. but I'm just emulating resolver with async and await. I'm not talking about optimizations. For calling code please refer to next.js example I linked to the question. So you can edit `apollo/resolvers.js` with contents I sent in the question and try to run. After you run it and disable javascript you'll see that there are no server-side rendered contents after gql query execution.

Comment: Well, if [this](https://github.com/zeit/next.js/blob/canary/examples/api-routes-apollo-server-and-client/apollo/resolvers.js) is the example you're trying to emulate, you can't do that with an `async` function or a function that returns a promise.  That example is a synchronous resolver.  You cannot EVER get a synchronous result out of `async` function or out of a promise or any function that obtains its result asynchronously.  Can't be done in Javascript.  The caller must use `await` or `.then()` to get the value out of the promise.

Comment: I've done enough guessing here about what you're trying to do.  If this isn't enough of a response for you, then please EDIT your question to add more detail that shows exactly what you're trying to do.  Or, you can wait and see if someone else who can figure out what you're trying to do comes along.  If that's the case, I'll bow out.

Comment: https://github.com/georgii-ivanov/next.js/tree/canary/examples/api-routes-apollo-server-and-client I need this example working on server-side. This is it. Now it's working on SSR only in case Promise already resolved. (`Promise.resolve(...data)`)

Comment: For SSR rendering, either you trigger GraphQL queries server-side, and then you have to wait for them to be resolved server-side, or you just render the template and trigger queries client-side. You *cannot* trigger queries server-side, pass unresolved promises to the client and have them be resolved client-side, that just won't work... So it's normal that in your example, SSR works only when the Promise resolves.

Comment: @Jaxx they use `apollo-link-schema`. I need it to be resolved and pass the result to the apollo state. Apollo can work with promises but this `apollo-link-schema` for some reason only uses resolved promises. I tried to call graphql request from graphql playground and timer worked fine! I need to have server blocked by request it's intended for me because I need those data for SEO

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is fully correct and not problem with SSR. I test your code with next.js example [api-routes-apollo-server-and-client](https://github.com/zeit/next.js/tree/canary/examples/api-routes-apollo-server-and-client) in CSR and SSR mode. For SSR test first run `npm run build` and then `npm start`. If your problem not solved try update node.js and re-download example code and again test it.

Comment: Thank you for the response. I'll check that all. I hope you right. I gave you my bounty cuz otherwise that'd be expired but you did your best with checking. Thank you. I'll keep you updated

Comment: Did that work for you? I've tried to do just that and found that its still populating the data into the state. I'm using the most recent version of the example. 
`<script id="__NEXT_DATA__" type="application/json">{"props":{"pageProps":{"apolloState":{}}},"page":"/","query":{},"buildId":"juZ1Po43r3rpqmYm354AX"}</script>`

Comment: What is your problem exactly?

Comment: Its not populating the html on that first load. With SSR I'd expect that the first page load fills the html with the data. I tried to do `build` then `start` but the result is still that the html isn't populated with the data. Right not it loads the HTML then makes the graphql call to get the data.

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to emulate the possible delay involved in resolving a remote request, or resolving promises in handlers in general, try this:

```js
export const resolvers = {
  Query: {
    async viewer(_parent, _args, _context, _info) {
      try {
        const resp = await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
          setTimeout(() => {
            resolve({ id: 1, name: 'John Smith', status: 'cached' })
          }, 1000)
        })
        return resp
      } catch (err) {
        throw new Error('failed')
      }
      // return { id: 1, name: 'John Smith', status: 'cached' }
    },
  },
}
```

`return await new Promise()` doesn't work because the await keyword doesn't do anything in that case, and the object returned is *still* a promise, where your resolvers expect the return value to be an object.

Assigning `await new Promise(...)` to a variable makes sure the promise resolves, and that the variable contains the expected object prior to being returned.

Comment: This doesn't work as expected. Static markup doesn't have state data from for SSR...

Comment: removed stuff about async/await because as I can see it's confusing for people. But question about different thing. About SSR static markup